# Is it possible to get other application version?

Tags: android

Is it possible to findout version of another application?
I can find if it is installed

```
android.content.pm.PackageManager mPm = getPackageManager();  // 1
PackageInfo info = mPm.getPackageInfo(pName, 0);  // 2,3
Boolean installed = info != null;
```

But i miss relative field in `packageinfo` or `applicationinfo`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`versionCode`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageInfo.html#versionCode) and [`versionName`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageInfo.html#versionName) are each fields in `PackageInfo`.